# Is there a link between the magicians in Egypt and their names Jannes and Jambres (as in the Bible)?

Tags: quran, bible, sihr, quranic-events, prophet-musa

In the Bible, there is a story from Paul:

**2 Timothy 3:8 ESV**

> Just as Jannes and Jambres opposed Moses, so these men also oppose the
>   truth, men corrupted in mind and disqualified regarding the faith.

Which points to an older story in Exodus:

**Exodus 7:11 ESV**

> Then Pharaoh summoned the wise men and the sorcerers, and they, the
>   magicians of Egypt, also did the same by their secret arts.

Is this same story in the Qur'an?  Specifically is there a direct link from the magicians in Egypt and their names Jannes and Jambres?

Comment: I was not sure if I have fully understood your question, but as you think the added comment can be an answer I delete my comment. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Quran states the story of some magicians from all around the Egypt who were gathered by Pharaoh to compete with Moses accompanied by his brother Aron --peace be upon them. However, Quran doesn't name any of them, only tells the story that the snake of Moses ate the magics of the magicians and they fell in prostration and became believers in God of Moses as they understood what Moses did was not a magic but a sign of power from his God. And seemingly those magicians who believed in Moses and his God were killed by Pharaoh as punishment:

> وَلَقَدْ أَرَيْنَاهُ آيَاتِنَا كُلَّهَا فَكَذَّبَ وَأَبَىٰ / قَالَ
>   أَجِئْتَنَا لِتُخْرِجَنَا مِنْ أَرْضِنَا بِسِحْرِكَ يَا مُوسَىٰ /
>   فَلَنَأْتِيَنَّكَ بِسِحْرٍ مِّثْلِهِ فَاجْعَلْ بَيْنَنَا وَبَيْنَكَ
>   مَوْعِدًا لَّا نُخْلِفُهُ نَحْنُ وَلَا أَنتَ مَكَانًا سُوًى / قَالَ
>   مَوْعِدُكُمْ يَوْمُ الزِّينَةِ وَأَن يُحْشَرَ النَّاسُ ضُحًى /
>   فَتَوَلَّىٰ فِرْعَوْنُ فَجَمَعَ كَيْدَهُ ثُمَّ أَتَىٰ / قَالَ لَهُم
>   مُّوسَىٰ وَيْلَكُمْ لَا تَفْتَرُوا عَلَى اللَّـهِ كَذِبًا
>   فَيُسْحِتَكُم بِعَذَابٍ ۖ وَقَدْ خَابَ مَنِ افْتَرَىٰ / فَتَنَازَعُوا
>   أَمْرَهُم بَيْنَهُمْ وَأَسَرُّوا النَّجْوَىٰ / قَالُوا إِنْ هَـٰذَانِ
>   لَسَاحِرَانِ يُرِيدَانِ أَن يُخْرِجَاكُم مِّنْ أَرْضِكُم بِسِحْرِهِمَا
>   وَيَذْهَبَا بِطَرِيقَتِكُمُ الْمُثْلَىٰ / فَأَجْمِعُوا كَيْدَكُمْ
>   ثُمَّ ائْتُوا صَفًّا ۚ وَقَدْ أَفْلَحَ الْيَوْمَ مَنِ اسْتَعْلَىٰ /
>   قَالُوا يَا مُوسَىٰ إِمَّا أَن تُلْقِيَ وَإِمَّا أَن نَّكُونَ أَوَّلَ
>   مَنْ أَلْقَىٰ / قَالَ بَلْ أَلْقُوا ۖ فَإِذَا حِبَالُهُمْ
>   وَعِصِيُّهُمْ يُخَيَّلُ إِلَيْهِ مِن سِحْرِهِمْ أَنَّهَا تَسْعَىٰ /
>   فَأَوْجَسَ فِي نَفْسِهِ خِيفَةً مُّوسَىٰ / قُلْنَا لَا تَخَفْ إِنَّكَ
>   أَنتَ الْأَعْلَىٰ / وَأَلْقِ مَا فِي يَمِينِكَ تَلْقَفْ مَا صَنَعُوا ۖ
>   إِنَّمَا صَنَعُوا كَيْدُ سَاحِرٍ ۖ وَلَا يُفْلِحُ السَّاحِرُ حَيْثُ
>   أَتَىٰ / فَأُلْقِيَ السَّحَرَةُ سُجَّدًا قَالُوا آمَنَّا بِرَبِّ
>   هَارُونَ وَمُوسَىٰ / قَالَ آمَنتُمْ لَهُ قَبْلَ أَنْ آذَنَ لَكُمْ ۖ
>   إِنَّهُ لَكَبِيرُكُمُ الَّذِي عَلَّمَكُمُ السِّحْرَ ۖ فَلَأُقَطِّعَنَّ
>   أَيْدِيَكُمْ وَأَرْجُلَكُم مِّنْ خِلَافٍ وَلَأُصَلِّبَنَّكُمْ فِي
>   جُذُوعِ النَّخْلِ وَلَتَعْلَمُنَّ أَيُّنَا أَشَدُّ عَذَابًا وَأَبْقَىٰ
>   / قَالُوا لَن نُّؤْثِرَكَ عَلَىٰ مَا جَاءَنَا مِنَ الْبَيِّنَاتِ
>   وَالَّذِي فَطَرَنَا ۖ فَاقْضِ مَا أَنتَ قَاضٍ ۖ إِنَّمَا تَقْضِي
>   هَـٰذِهِ الْحَيَاةَ الدُّنْيَا / إِنَّا آمَنَّا بِرَبِّنَا لِيَغْفِرَ
>   لَنَا خَطَايَانَا وَمَا أَكْرَهْتَنَا عَلَيْهِ مِنَ السِّحْرِ ۗ
>   وَاللَّـهُ خَيْرٌ وَأَبْقَىٰ / إِنَّهُ مَن يَأْتِ رَبَّهُ مُجْرِمًا
>   فَإِنَّ لَهُ جَهَنَّمَ لَا يَمُوتُ فِيهَا وَلَا يَحْيَىٰ / وَمَن
>   يَأْتِهِ مُؤْمِنًا قَدْ عَمِلَ الصَّالِحَاتِ فَأُولَـٰئِكَ لَهُمُ
>   الدَّرَجَاتُ الْعُلَىٰ / جَنَّاتُ عَدْنٍ تَجْرِي مِن تَحْتِهَا
>   الْأَنْهَارُ خَالِدِينَ فِيهَا ۚ وَذَٰلِكَ جَزَاءُ مَن تَزَكَّىٰ
>
> And We showed Pharaoh all Our Signs, but he did reject and refuse. /
>   He said: "Hast thou come to drive us out of our land with thy magic, O
>   Moses? / "But we can surely produce magic to match thine! So make a
>   tryst between us and thee, which we shall not fail to keep - neither
>   we nor thou - in a place where both shall have even chances." / Moses
>   said: "Your tryst is the Day of the Festival, and let the people be
>   assembled when the sun is well up." / So Pharaoh withdrew: He
>   concerted his plan, and then came (back). / Moses said to him: Woe to
>   you! Forge not ye a lie against Allah, lest He destroy you (at once)
>   utterly by chastisement: the forger must suffer frustration!" / So
>   they disputed, one with another, over their affair, but they kept
>   their talk secret. / They said: "These two are certainly (expert)
>   magicians: their object is to drive you out from your land with their
>   magic, and to do away with your most cherished institutions. /
>   "Therefore concert your plan, and then assemble in (serried) ranks: He
>   wins (all along) today who gains the upper hand." / They said: "O
>   Moses! whether wilt thou that thou throw (first) or that we be the
>   first to throw?" / He said, "Nay, throw ye first!" Then behold their
>   ropes and their rods-so it seemed to him on account of their magic -
>   began to be in lively motion! / So Moses conceived in his mind a (sort
>   of) fear. / We said: "Fear not! for thou hast indeed the upper hand: /
>   "Throw that which is in thy right hand: Quickly will it swallow up
>   that which they have faked what they have faked is but a magician's
>   trick: and the magician thrives not, (no matter) where he goes." / So
>   the magicians were thrown down to prostration: they said, "We believe
>   in the Lord of Aaron and Moses". / (Pharaoh) said: "Believe ye in Him
>   before I give you permission? Surely this must be your leader, who has
>   taught you magic! be sure I will cut off your hands and feet on
>   opposite sides, and I will have you crucified on trunks of palm-trees:
>   so shall ye know for certain, which of us can give the more severe and
>   the more lasting punishment!" / They said: "Never shall we regard thee
>   as more than the Clear Signs that have come to us, or than Him Who
>   created us! so decree whatever thou desirest to decree: for thou canst
>   only decree (touching) the life of this world. / "For us, we have
>   believed in our Lord: may He forgive us our faults, and the magic to
>   which thou didst compel us: for Allah is Best and Most Abiding." /
>   Verily he who comes to his Lord as a sinner (at Judgment),- for him is
>   Hell: therein shall he neither die nor live. / But such as come to Him
>   as Believers who have worked righteous deeds,- for them are ranks
>   exalted,- / Gardens of Eternity, beneath which flow rivers: they will
>   dwell therein for aye: such is the reward of those who purify
>   themselves (from evil). [20:56-76]

But I don't know anything about the name of the magicians, maybe someone else could find a Hadeeth about that. Godspeed.